# C# process data from one webmethod to another

Tags: c#, asmx, webmethod

I have two working webmethods, one reads data from customer database on the other hand the other one writes data to another customer db.

I want to connect these methods together to create a bulk dataflow.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "namespace")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();




    [WebMethod]
    public string GetCustomer(String CustomerName, String CustomerSurName, String CustomerAddress, String CustomerEmail, String CustomerPhone,
        String Barcode, String StoreName, String City, String Town, String BirthDay, String CreateDate, String Signature,
        String IsProcessed, String CreateDateHour, String IsChecked, String IsEmpty)
    {
        var json = "";
        var getcustomer = from result in dc.CustomerInfos
                          where result.CustomerName == CustomerName
                         select result;

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        json = jss.Serialize(getcustomer);

        return json;
    }


    public int MyConnectionString2 { get; private set; }

    [WebMethod]
    public string insertCustomer (String CustomerName, String CustomerSurName, String CustomerAddress, String CustomerEmail, String CustomerPhone,
        String Barcode, String StoreName, String City, String Town, String BirthDay, String CreateDate, String Signature,
        String IsProcessed, String CreateDateHour, String IsChecked, String IsEmpty)
    {


        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString2"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
        sqlCon.Open();
        nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "INSERT  INTO CustomerInfos (CustomerName, CustomerSurName, CustomerAddress, CustomerEmail, CustomerPhone, Barcode, StoreName, City, Town, BirthDay, CreateDate, Signature, IsProcessed, CreateDateHour, IsChecked, IsEmpty) VALUES (@CustomerName, @CustomerSurname, @CustomerAddress, @CustomerEmail, @CustomerPhone, @Barcode, @StoreName, @City, @Town, @BirthDay, @CreateDate, @Signature, @IsProcessed, @CreateDateHour, @IsChecked, @IsEmpty)";
        // Add Parameters to Command Parameters collection
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerSurName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerPhone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Barcode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@StoreName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Town", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@BirthDay", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@CreateDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Signature", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsProcessed", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@CreateDateHour", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsChecked", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsEmpty", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);


        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@CustomerName"].Value = CustomerName;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@customerSurname"].Value = CustomerSurName;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@CustomerAddress"].Value = CustomerAddress;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@CustomerEmail"].Value = CustomerEmail;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@CustomerPhone"].Value = CustomerPhone;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Barcode"].Value = Barcode;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@StoreName"].Value = StoreName;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@City"].Value = City;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Town"].Value = Town;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@BirthDay"].Value = BirthDay;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@CreateDate"].Value = CreateDate;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Signature"].Value = Signature;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@IsProcessed"].Value = IsProcessed;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@CreateDateHour"].Value = CreateDateHour;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@IsChecked"].Value = IsChecked;
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@IsEmpty"].Value = IsEmpty;


        nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return "done";


    }

}
```

What am i supposed to do next? Any clues?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So you want to select the customer and insert it in the other db?

Comment: Indeed, i have two database servers, and two webmethods, i ve tried almost everything. Seperated those two webmethods to two webservices. How can i consume from getCustomer and write using insertCustomer?

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all move the methods implementation into two new classes:

```
public class SourceCustomerRepository
  {

    public CustomerInfo GetCustomer(String CustomerName, String CustomerSurName, String CustomerAddress, String CustomerEmail, String CustomerPhone,
        String Barcode, String StoreName, String City, String Town, String BirthDay, String CreateDate, String Signature,
        String IsProcessed, String CreateDateHour, String IsChecked, String IsEmpty)
    {
      return from result in dc.CustomerInfos
      where result.CustomerName == CustomerName
      select result;
    }

  }
```

refactor get customer web method to:

```
var customerRepo=new SourceCustomerRepository();
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      var customer = customerRepo.GetCustomer(CustomerName, CustomerSurName, CustomerAddress, CustomerEmail,
        CustomerPhone, Barcode, StoreName, City, Town, BirthDay, CreateDate, Signature, IsProcessed, CreateDateHour,
        IsChecked, IsEmpty);
      json = jss.Serialize();

      return json;
```

Do the same with insertCustomer method. Then you can reuse these two new classes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply however i could not manage to do it. How exactly shall i set your method sir?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the client script to call the web services.

Here is the link which would be helpful for you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=vs.90).aspx

Also you can call web service through some ajax call also.